# str_replace and ucwords for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am struggling to get `$_POST` values capitalize and removing underscore if it is not the `mailaddress` field. I am almost there but not able to remove the underscore from checkbox group array. Also, I believe, there must be some better way to optimize this code.

```
$_POST = str_replace( '_', ' ', $_POST );

foreach ( $_POST as $k => $v ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $v ) && $k != 'mailaddress' ) {
        $_POST[ $k ] = ucwords( $v );
    } else if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
        $_POST[ $k ] = array_map( 'ucwords', $v );
    }
}
```

## Input

```
Array
(
    [Q1] => Array
        (
            [0] => tag
            [1] => bil_mc
            [2] => cykel_gang
        )

    [Q2] => 1 3 ganger per manad
    [Q3] => pa fritiden
    [Q4] => Array
        (
            [0] => koper_biljett_i_appen
            [1] => jojo_reskassa
            [2] => jojo_period
            [3] => reser_aldrig_kollektivt
        )

    [mailaddress] => 'me@email.com'

    ...

);
```

## Looking for end result

```
Array
(
    [Q1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tag
            [1] => Bil Mc
            [2] => Cykel Gang
        )

    [Q2] => 1 3 Ganger Per Manad
    [Q3] => Pa Fritiden
    [Q4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Koper Biljett I Appen
            [1] => Jojo Reskassa
            [2] => Jojo Period
            [3] => Reser Aldrig Kollektivt
        )

    [mailaddress] => 'me@email.com'

    ...

);
```

Any help or sugession please???

Comment: Can you share your input `$_POST` and expected output?

Comment: Obviously `str_replace` does not replace in subarrays

Comment: You should apply the `str_replace()` function in `foreach()`.

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, I have tried using in foreach but didn't work for whatever reason. no idea. why

Comment: @CoursesWeb I have tried before posting here, but it didn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: I don't know who is giving the vote to close the question but if I am that master like you then never would be posted. So do not be in a hurry to hit the close vote button.

Comment: I don't think the close vote is in any way wrong. You have added your input/output, but before that your question was not on par with minimum complete verifiable example. Even now the arrays are in wrong format so we can't just copy paste them and try ourselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `str_replace` does not work with subarrays, you have to use it on every subarray of `$_POST`:

```
foreach ( $_POST as $k => $v ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $v ) && $k != 'mailaddress' ) {
        $_POST[ $k ] = str_replace( '_', ' ', ucwords( $v ) );
    } else if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
        $_POST[ $k ] = array_map( 'ucwords', str_replace( '_', ' ', $v ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The solution is working fine.I didn't know I can use str_replace in such a way passing into `array_map`. Thanks once again to learn me new thing. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be able to use `array_walk` or `array_walk_recursive` with a callback to achieve this?

```
array_walk_recursive( $_POST, function($v,$k){
    if( $k!='mailaddress' )return ucwords( str_replace( '_',' ', strtolower( $v ) ) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest using `var_export($array)` instead of `print_r($array)`

If you look at the below ( output from var_export() ) you'll see it's properly formatted as PHP code, unlike `print_r`.  I say this because it took me almost as much time to fix the array as it did to solve the problem.  You can also pass `true` as the second parameter and get the output as a string ( see below )

```
$A = Array(
    'Q1' => Array(
        0 => 'tag',
        1 => 'bil_mc',
        2 => 'cykel_gang'
    ),
    'Q2' => '1 3 ganger per manad',
    'Q3' => 'pa fritiden',
    'Q4' => Array(
        0 => 'koper_biljett_i_appen',
        1 => 'jojo_reskassa',
        2 => 'jojo_period',
        3 => 'reser_aldrig_kollektivt',
     ),
    'mailaddress' => 'me@email.com'
);

foreach($A as $key => &$value){
    //check if the first character of the key is 'Q', I thought about using.
    // if( preg_match('/^Q[0-9]+$/', $key ) - but substr is like 10x faster
    if( substr($key,0,1) == 'Q')
        $value = ucUnderline( $value );      
}

function ucUnderline($mixed)
{
    if(is_array($mixed)){
        foreach($mixed as &$value){
            $value = ucUnderline($value); //recursive
        }
        return $mixed;
    }else{
        return ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $mixed));
    }
}

$o = var_export($A, true);
echo "<code>$o</code>";
```

Outputs ( the beauty of var_export )

```
array (
    'Q1' =>
    array (
        0 => 'Tag',
        1 => 'Bil Mc',
        2 => 'Cykel Gang',
    ),
    'Q2' => '1 3 Ganger Per Manad',
    'Q3' => 'Pa Fritiden',
    'Q4' =>
    array (
        0 => 'Koper Biljett I Appen',
        1 => 'Jojo Reskassa',
        2 => 'Jojo Period',
        3 => 'Reser Aldrig Kollektivt',
    ),
    'mailaddress' => 'me@email.com',
)
```

I chose to add this because it uses a recursive function, the benefit of course is you can use it again some where else.  I am also using pass by reference `&` in the foreach loops to make life a bit easier. Last thing is that right now you only have `mailaddress` and the `Q[0-9]+` keys in the top level array.  I noticed everyone else was explicitly ignoring the `mailaddress` where Mine ignores the non `Q` type which if you add additional elements to the array that you don't want modified, you may find it useful. Instead of having to explicitly ignore those 'additional' items.